# How to divide an image into 8 regions using Matlab

Tags: image-processing, matlab

I have 256x256 image, Is there any easy way to divide it into 8 regions(32x32) and get a specific region? Ex.: region 4,6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An image is stored as a 2-dimensional array.

```
function region = fnGetRegion(C,I,J);
% C is 256x256 image, I, J each range 1:8 to get 32x32 subregion of C
region = C((I-1)*32+[1:32],(J-1)*32+[1:32]);
end
```